# can gensub() accept function calls as second arguments?

Tags: awk

Inspired by this [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201508/vowels-up-consonants-down) challenge, I thought it would be easy to achieve the end result with awk. The algorithm would be: convert everything to lowercase, then get only vowels to uppercase.

I thought this could work

```
awk '{$0=tolower($0);print gensub(/[aeiou]/,toupper("&"),"g")}'
> HeLlO
> hello
```

but all it does is echoing the input in lowercase. Then, I just went about fiddling with it:

```
$ awk '{$0=tolower($0);print gensub(/[aeiou]/,"&"toupper("&"),"g")}'
> HeLlO
> heelloo
```

I was about to conclude that maybe the parser was reading `"&""&"`, since awk can be very forgiving at times. But then, I tried with other functions:

```
$ awk '{$0=tolower($0);print gensub(/[aeiou]/,strtonum("&"),"g")}'
> HeLlO
> h0ll0
```

So, in conclusion, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can gensub() accept function calls as second arguments?

No. Awk is not a functional programming language; arguments to a function are evaluated immediately before that function is executed.

> what am I missing?

`toupper("&")` yields `&` back, `"&"toupper("&")` evaluates to `"&&"`, hence `ee` and `oo`.

And `strtonum("&")` returns `0`, so you're replacing `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u` with `0` there.

Comment: Right! so, the function actually evaluates, but rather than using the "special" meaning of "&", it tries to return capital&. But I still wonder, if there could be a way to do it with a trick.  Many functions in awk do populate predefined variables. Here I'm thinking about SYMTAB, but could be something else. The `match()` function, for instance, does provide interface for it. I wonder if any of the subs do as well.

Comment: @Daemon In standard awk, there is no way of doing it that way due to the language's design. And I don't think it's possible to implement such a feature in gawk without changing a lot of things.

Comment: Right, you cannot do this with any of the `*sub()` functions. You can do what you want in GNU awk though by using `match()` instead of `gensub()`, e.g. a single `sub()`-equivalent (but right-to-left matching, you'd have to change the regexp or otherwise modify the code to get left-to-right) would be `match($0,/(.*)([aeiou])(.*)/,a) { $0=a[1] toupper(a[2]) a[3] }` and `gsub()`-equivalent would be `while ( match($0,/(.*)([aeiou])(.*)/,a) ) { $0=a[1] toupper(a[2]) a[3] }`.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure you understand why there is no possible "trick" to make this work with any of the sub() functions - in `foo(bar())` the function `bar()` **is called first** and then its result is passed as an argument to the function `foo()`. So there is no possible way that anything related to `foo()`, can impact the execution of `bar()` since `bar()` ran before `foo()` was ever called.